# Speakable schema JSON-LD not working

Tags: schema.org

*Asking here because HubSpot support hasn't been any help.*

We want to optimize some of our HubSpot webpages for voice SEO/Google Home. We learned about this speakable schema: https://pending.schema.org/speakable

I copied/pasted the JSON-LD code into the head HTML section of this page: [REDACTED URL]

It's not working properly. Look at what happens: [REDACTED URL]

All the markup is showing up to the user on the front-end. That obviously isn't right. Any advice/what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON-LD is a script; therefore, you have to put your JSON code inside an opening and closing `script` tags:

`<script type="application/ld+json"> ...your JSON code... </script>`

Try it in your browser's DevTools and your page will display as intended.

Now, for allowing Google to recognize your markup. First, this is the [recommended](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/speakable) (and much clearer) spec to go off. It is Google's own documentation; things that are not yet in the [full list](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery) of recognized markup will not have any effect in Google, and will probably not be recognized by [their testing tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) either.

Second, note that this is still in Beta. That means it's somewhat under construction, so the testing tool may encounter errors until it's out of Beta. That said...

Here is the valid JSON for your case; when you run it in a [JSON formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), it passes the test:

```
{
   "@context":"https://schema.org/",
   "@type":"WebPage",
   "name":"Front Row Cyber Insurance",
   "speakable":{
      "@type":"SpeakableSpecification",
      "cssSelector":[
         "headline",
         "summary"
      ]
   },
   "url":"https://www.frontrowinsurance.com/articles/online-cyber-insurance-for-canadian-small-businesses"
}
```

And that's it, that's all you need. This goes inside those `script` tags. But there is more work to do.

Looking at your website's code, I see a lot of inline styles instead of CSS classes. What you should do is apply a class to all the HTML elements you want to be speakable. This will have to be added in your CMS. Let's say you create a class (with no styles, just for element selection) of `.speakabletext`. Your HTML may now look like:

`<p class="speakabletext">`

Once this class is applied to all the HTML elements you want to be speakable, like paragraphs and headlines, you do not need to define it in your CSS file, since it has no styles associated with it. Just swap it into your JSON, which is now:

```
{
   "@context":"https://schema.org/",
   "@type":"WebPage",
   "name":"Front Row Cyber Insurance",
   "speakable":{
      "@type":"SpeakableSpecification",
      "cssSelector":[
         "speakabletext"
      ]
   },
   "url":"https://www.frontrowinsurance.com/articles/online-cyber-insurance-for-canadian-small-businesses"
}
```

Run that through the JSON validator first. Once it passes, run it through the schema testing tool. See what happens.

Comment: That fixed the code issue, it seems, but now the weird thing is when I go to test this: https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?

Google says "Page partially loaded" and I cannot find the speakable schema listed anywhere in these results. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Yes @gpgpgp - that has more to do with the JSON formatting. In other words, your code has invalid characters/structures. Run your JSON (without the script tags) through a JSON formatter/validator like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ or https://jsonlint.com/ (I used the first one) and it'll tell you where the errors are and what to fix.

Comment: How could it have invalid characters when I just copied/pasted from the official schema: https://pending.schema.org/speakable ? Very confusing.

Comment: Anyway, I just copied in the "fixed" code from jsonformatter, ran the URL through Google rich results tester again, and I'm still not seeing speakable schema.

Comment: Hey @gpgpgp I amended the answer above with what I hope is a complete solution. Please reread all of it as I added to the script tag code as well.

Comment: I followed your <p class="speakabletext"> solution. It appears in Rich Results Test, finally, as an Image, not a Script. So I wonder if something is still wrong.

Comment: @gpgpgp Interesting... I examined your on-page code now, seems legit... There might be other site issues, like an unindexed page or robotx.txt blocking, or something else. Or else the feature is still in Beta so there are bugs. Not sure what the issue is, but use https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7445569 and https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7552505#missing-jobs to troubleshoot...